# Get value of aria-invalid of text box in python using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I want get the attribute of the text field. when click the signin button. It vanishes the *aria-invalid* attrib after reloading. so i want to get the *aria-invalid* attribute of the text field when click while loading the page but not after the page loaded.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9lK4.jpg)

when clicking only *aria-invalid* appears in the text field and after click and the signin button, *aria-invalid* disappears.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("captchaCode").send_keys(captcha) #captcha =value
            
# We wait for the menu elemant to be clickable
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signinBtn"]')))
            
captchaCode_input = driver.find_element_by_id("captchaCode")
print("Get value of aria-invalid - ",captchaCode_input.get_attribute('aria-invalid')) 
            
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach could be set your page timeout quite low for your element( So your execution moves to next line even before page is loaded completely).

```
   try:
     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signinBtn"]')))
   except TimeoutException:
   pass
       
 print("Get value of aria-invalid - 
 ",driver.find_element_by_id("captchaCode").get_attribute('aria-invalid'))
```

Note: You can reduce wait time if it loading that fast.